# Is 'ClosedInterval<T>' does not have a member named 'Generator' with regards to CGFloat a bug?

Tags: swift

I already posted on the Apple Dev Forums but didn't get any response, so apologies if you've already seen this. I have a new (potential) bug I'm seeing in Beta 5 and I'm wondeirng if anyone has a workaround.

This line was working fine in Beta 4:

```
for i in 0 ... tiledMap.mapSize.width {
```

tiledMap.mapSize.width is a CGFloat

In beta 5, Swift complains:

```
'ClosedInterval<T>' does not have a member named 'Generator'
```

If I switch tileMap.mapSize.width to a constant like 25, the code compiles of course:

```
for i in 0 ... 25 {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be defined in the Swift book, but think it's reasonable that the range operators `...` and `..<` don't work for floating types (Float, Double, CGFloat...) in `for ... in` loops. I think that might lead to confounded expectations and confusion, as floating types don't really *have* a sensible set of values to step through in the ranges between two of their values.

You could argue that the ranges should step through the integer values in between the start and end points, but (a) there may not be a precise float representation of a given integer, and (b) what happens if the start and end points aren't integer in the first place? (e.g. `for i in 0.3846...837.8`) Some might even expect `for ... in` to loop through all possible floating values in the range—that's what happens for integers.

To me, the language design is good here: if you want to step through certain points between two float values, you should have to make it explicit and use a different loop construct that makes it clearer what's going on:

```
for var i:CGFloat = 0; i <= tiledMap.mapSize.width; i++ {
```

It's worth nothing that floats are strideable, too:

```
for i in stride(from: 0.0, through: tiledMap.mapSize.width, by: 1.0) {
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but I think the `...` should work with floating points. Of course not for array indexes, but there may be many other uses of _range_. Example `size.isIn(2.5...3.5)`.

Comment: @iMartin And some of those *do* work. For example, `case 2.5...3.5:` is a valid case for a Float in a `switch` statement.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right! It would be great if they get this consistent in 1.0

Comment: @MattGibson I appreciate the answer and of course what you wrote makes perfect sense - I was just puzzled because this had been working on earlier betas and now it doesn't and I didn't see it in the release notes (unless I missed it). Thanks!

Comment: @davecom Well, in some ways, it's just my opinion rather than a "proper" answer, because the behaviour just isn't defined yet. It might be that what I've said turns out only to be true for beta 5. But I think it makes sense. (It looks like if you want to make it work again, it may be a matter of implementing Incrementable for floats yourself, but I've not tried it.)